# Move folders in Subversion using Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rename

I've been creating milestones of trunk inside branches folder. But they are getting numerous, and are all related, so I decided to create a /branches/milestones/1.0.0/ and throw all 1.0.0 version's milestones in there.

If it was a rename, Tortoise has the rename feature. But how about moving all files inside a folder? how to make Subversion understand it and keep track instead of think it was a delete-add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Subversion, rename & move are synonymous. Both are implemented as a copy with history immediately followed by a delete.

Comment: But when I use tortoise to rename, it wants to commit a delete and an add to Subversion. And when I use it's branch feature, I see no tracks in branch files of trunk commits. And I see no Tortoise feature for moving a folder.

Comment: Should I just select a folder for rename and set it from "1.0.0-a10" to "milestones/1.0.0/1.0.0-a10"?

Comment: A rename *is* a delete and add with history, which is why you're seeing that. You'll only see an option for Move if you right-click & drag an item in Explorer, or you can move directly via the repository browser.